# Constant difference symbol

Tags: notation, hyperoperation

A simple notation question: I'm familiar with the notation $a \propto b$, which means $a$ and $b$ are constant multiples of each other, but is there an analogous symbol for when $a$ and $b$ differ by a constant? For instance, when $a \propto b$, what symbol belongs between $\log a$ and $\log b$? Is there one?

EDIT: recalling [Knuth's up arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation), it occurs to me that there might be similar notation for the relationship $a[n]k = b$, for any hyperoperation $[n]$ and constant $k$. Is $a \propto^{(n)} b$ accepted notation? Admittedly, it's hard to imagine this being very useful beyond $n=1,2,3$ (addition, multiplication, exponentiation).

Comment: I doubt that there is any such notation, beyond $a = b + k$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be because what you $a=b+k$ isn't that cumbersome to write. But I was curious. Thanks.

Comment: For $a-b$ constant, you could write $e^a\propto e^b$.